# Get revision number from commit ID and vice versa in Git

Tags: git

I know that this is possible because I've seen it done before. That Git uses hashes to identify revisions is irrelevant because a repository still has a record of the order that various revisions were committed in.

Given a Git repository's commit ID, how do you get the ordinal revision number that corresponds to it (NOT for a particular file)? Given a revision number (i.e., 1, 2, etc.) of the repository (NOT of a particular file), how do you obtain the commit ID?

Comment: From commit to revision number is `git rev-list --count <commit_id>`

Comment: how do you want to count if your current branch has commits that are on different branches ? lets say you have master where you implemented a feature on a feature branch and then merged back to master ? so, do you include all the commits from the feature branch or only count commits on the master branch (first-parent) ?

Comment: This is a tricky question for git because, how do you number revisions in parallel branches? If it were a straight branch from the beginning, you might have a clear answer.

Comment: so that leads to two options:
count all suggested by : @CoryKramer
or add "--first-parent" to his answer to only follow the main path.

Comment: @eftshift0 I don't see how its tricky. If it were a problem for what I ask, then it would be a problem for the commit hash since the hash incorporates parallel branches in its calculation. The revision number *of an entire repository* would increment *any time a commit is made to it*.

Comment: I think I am not explaining myself very well... suppose you want to get the revision number of a revision from master.... a revision from a feature branch.... there were 20 features being developed at the same time when that feature branch was being developed. So, you have all those revisions going on at _about_ the same time in parallel. How do you number them? Another tricky question: how about _orphan_ branches being added into that same repo. How does that affect your calculation? So, it's not a _single-straight-answer_ question (and I can think of more scenarios to consider)

Comment: IOW, you might find a way to more-or-less match what you want, but your way to devise it will for sure not be the only way to solve it because there are many ways to look at the problem.

Comment: @Melab And what about commits created in other repositories and fetched later?

Comment: @phd that one is beautiful. You have your magic ordinal revision number... then you fetch (or push into a remote repo) and it gets busted. Nice.

Comment: @Melab "I've seen it done before" : would you care to describe how, or where ?

Comment: Say, you could try this: `git log --pretty=%h the-revision | wc -l`. That should give you a revision ordinal _number_... but do not think this is a straight way to pinpoint a revision in a repo. You might have other revisions that will give you the same result **in the same repo**.... and if anybody said to me "look at revision 300 in repo X" I would ask them to kindly provide me with a revision **ID** because a revision ordinal number is not a proper way to pinpoint a revision in a git repo.

Comment: @phd You ask `And what about commits created in other repositories and fetched later?`. The answer is "Nothing.". It's only one repository I'm looking at.

Comment: @Melab "*It's only one repository I'm looking at.*" That doesn't really matter. Git is intended for a different use case — async distributed VCS. Because of that it doesn't provide tools you're looking for, There is no way to properly count commits, and especially there is no way to go from a counter to hash ID.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this is possible because I've seen it done before.

[It Ain’t What You Don’t Know That Gets You Into Trouble. It’s What You Know for Sure That Just Ain’t So.](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2018/11/18/know-trouble/)

The best way to get close to something *like* what you want is to use `git describe`.  See [the `git describe` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for details.

Mercurial repositories do have simple ordinal numbers, as Mercurial's repository structure is a relatively simple append-only database.  Each commit in a Mercurial repository *also* has a unique hash ID.  You can use either with `-r`, so `-r 123` gets you commit #123, which might have hash ID `a123456` (abbreviated).  This is quite convenient ... and a deadly trap.  What happens is that Alice and Bob both clone some particular Mercurial repository, which has, say, 1326 commits in it.  Their `-r` numbers now correspond exactly for *all these commits* because their clones started with the *same 1326 commits*, in the same sequence.

Now Alice adds, to her clone, a few new commits, perhaps on a new branch or bookmark.  Bob adds a few new commits as well, to his clone.  *Both of them get the same `-r` numbers for their new commits*.

Bob and Alice start chatting (perhaps by email, or on Slack, or super-old-school at the water cooler, or however this works wherever they work).  They talk about something in -r 734, and they both look and see the *same commit*.  They wonder if a bug was introduced in -r 922, and they both look at that, and *see the same commit* again.  *Aha*, they think to themselves, *we can ignore those big ugly hash IDs, these simple sequential revision numbers are so much easier, let's just use them!*

Eventually, Alice and Bob send their commits to the company's main Mercurial repository.  One of them—let's say Alice—pushes before the other ... so in the *central repository*, Alice's commits *keep their numbers*, but when Bob gets to it, *Bob's* commits *get renumbered* there.  Bob pulls (before or after) and gets Alice's commits, using *new and different numbers*.

From now on, *Bob's revision numbers are out of sync with everyone else's*.  Bob's `-r 1328`, in Bob's Mercurial repository, is *Bob's commit*.  But to Alice and others, `-r 1328` is *Alice's commit*.  Bob's commits don't start until `-r 1331`.

In a later conversation, Alice and Bob are trying to talk about one or both of their new commits.  They get totally mixed up, because Bob thinks Alice is talking about *Bob's* commits, and Alice thinks Bob is talking about *Alice's* commits.  This all falls apart *because these simple, linear `-r` numbers are not universal.*

Git never made this particular mistake (though Git made plenty of others of course).  Do not try to do this; it is a bad idea.  If a particular commit is important enough to have a universal-ish name, *give it a tag*.

Comment: That information about unsynchronized commits is all very interesting, but not terribly relevant. I'm focusing on a single repository, no clones.

Comment: As phd said in the comments below your question, that's not relevant to *Git*. Git does not provide the tool you want because that tool won't work when the database *is* distributed. You may be able to abuse `git rev-list --count` in a way that's useful to you, but be aware that this is very fragile. Don't do it if you have *any* other option.